How to add new classes for trained model YOLOV8
I want to add new classes for my model so I don't have to re-train it how can I do that? My model is of type classify YOLOV8.
I've already tried just training the model, but it didn't work.
Is it better for me to use CLI method if you know, please help me.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You cannot add new classes without having to train.
